# How to read values from two services at once

Tags: java, android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am working on a project using BLE and want to read values from two services at once but i only get the value from the first one

My onServicesDiscovered code is

```
public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) 
{
        for (BluetoothGattService service : gatt.getServices()) {
            if ((service == null) || (service.getUuid() == null)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (BleUuid.SERVICE_DEVICE_INFORMATION.equalsIgnoreCase(service
                    .getUuid().toString())) 
            {  
              mConnGatt.readCharacteristic(service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(BleUuid.CHAR_MANUFACTURER_NAME_STRING)));
            }
            if (BleUuid.CHAR_ALERT_LEVEL.equalsIgnoreCase(service
                    .getUuid().toString())) 
            {
              mConnGatt.readCharacteristic(service.getCharacteristic(UUID.fromString(BleUuid.CHAR_SERIAL_NUMBEAR_STRING)));
            }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have one outstanding GATT operation at a time (readCharacteristic, writeCharacteristic, readDescriptor, writeDescriptor, requestMtu). You need to wait for the corresponding callback (onCharacteristicRead etc.) until you can execute a new one.